# How to combine two dataframes and average like values?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to machine learning. I have two dataframes that have movie ratings in them. Some of the movie ratings have the same movie title, but different number ratings while other rows have movie titles that the other data frame doesn't have. I was wondering how I would be able to combine the two dataframes and average any ratings that have the same movie name. Thanks for the help!

[image: example]

Comment: Removed `machine-learning` and `numpy` tag it has nothing to do with the question. And please don't post images of data frame, transcribing images is tedious, instead post `df.to_dict()` to the question. It makes reproducing your data locally very easy. Please go through [How to make good pandas reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html)

```
# df = pd.DataFrame({'Movie':['IR', 'R'], 'rating':[95, 90], 'director':['SB', 'RC']})
# df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Movie':['IR', 'BH'], 'rating':[93, 88], 'direction':['SB', 'RC']})

(pd.concat([df, df1]).groupby('Movie', as_index=False).
                      agg({'rating':'mean', 'director':'first'}))

  Movie  rating director
0    BH      88       RC
1    IR      94       SB
2     R      90       RC
```

Or [`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
df.append(df1).groupby('Movie',as_index=False).agg({'rating':'mean', 'director':'first'})

  Movie  rating director
0    BH      88       RC
1    IR      94       SB
2     R      90       RC
```

- If you want `Movie` column as index, `as_index` parameter of `df.groupby` defaults to `True`, `Movie` column would be index, remove `as_index=False` from `groupby`
- If you want to maintain the order then set `sort` parameter to `True`in `groupby`.

  ```
  (df.append(df1).groupby('Movie',as_index=False, sort=False).
                  agg({'rating':'mean', 'director':'first'}))

      Movie  rating director
  0    IR      94       SB
  1     R      90       RC
  2    BH      88       RC
  ```